# Draggable elements in an auto overflow container using Muuri

Tags: draggable, webflow, muuri

**The goal:** using [Muuri](https://docs.muuri.dev/) to create draggable elements in a container with auto oveflow

**The problem:** The elements that should be contained are ovelapping the container (which is in blue) - see below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwi9n.png)

[see site example](https://brand-toys.webflow.io/contentgrid#) here

I tried to use ChatGPT to solve the problem but have had no luck

Here's [link](https://chat.openai.com/share/cd0d47bc-5ccb-4893-8e35-cadca7c957dc) to me trying to work it out

I tried to use CSS in the site Head:

```
<style>
#muuri-container {
                        height: auto;
            min-height: auto; /* or whatever height you prefer */
            overflow: auto;
        }
#muuri, #muuri * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    </style>
```

and the following code in the site Footer:

```
<!-- [Muuri masonry grid] -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/muuri@0.9.5/dist/muuri.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web-animations-js@2.3.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var grid = new Muuri("#muuri-container", {
    dragContainer: document.getElementById("muuri-container"),
    dragEnabled: true,
    fillGaps: true,
    alignRight: false,
    alignBottom: false,
    itemPlaceholderClass: "foo-item-placeholder",
    dragPlaceholder: {
      enabled: true,
      createElement(item) {
        return item.getElement().cloneNode(true);
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>


<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var grid = new Muuri("#muuri-container", {
    dragContainer: document.getElementById("muuri-container"),
    dragEnabled: true,
    fillGaps: true,
    alignRight: false,
    alignBottom: false,
    layoutOnInit: true,
    layoutOnResize: 150, // Adjust debounce time as needed
    itemPlaceholderClass: "foo-item-placeholder",
    dragPlaceholder: {
      enabled: true,
      createElement(item) {
        return item.getElement().cloneNode(true);
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

It hasn't worked.

The draggable elements don't have a z index so I don't get why it keeps overlapping the container.

Please help.